# The tooltip for the data points in the React Native Gifted Charts is not displayed when clicking on points that are outside the current view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, charts

I trust you're doing well.

I've been actively engaged with the charts in my application, and to achieve this, I've employed the **react-native-gifted-charts** library.

The graphs are functioning as expected, but I'm currently facing an issue where the tooltip fails to appear when hovering or clicking on a data point that lies outside the visible portion of the chart. To provide some context, my dataset consists of 52 x-axis points, but when the chart's current view displays only a subset, let's say 12 points, the tooltip only works for those 12 points and not beyond.

Initially, I made use of the scrollable x-axis feature since I have 52 data points, but when I integrated the **pointerConfig**, the scrolling functionality ceased to work. To work around this, I implemented a **ScrollView**, which addressed the scrolling issue but, unfortunately, caused the tooltip to become non-functional for data points that fall outside the current view.

**Note:** I have also tried to pass *ref* so that when I scroll the View, then I will get the data from the current graph, and will populate the new points, but that didn't work either

In the first picture as you can see the tooltip is showing (datapoint 0 has been clicked), becuase its in the current view, but not in the second image (datapoint 13 has been clicked)

[image]
[image]

1st image : data point 4 clicked, 2nd image data point 24 clicked

[image]
[image]

**package.json**

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.4",
"react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.3.11",
```

**code**

```js
               <GraphWrapper>
                  <GraphContainer
                    horizontal={true}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                    <LineChart
                      areaChart
                      isAnimated
                      thickness={3}
                      maxValue={100}
                      startOpacity={1}
                      noOfSections={5}
                      data={chartData}
                      rulesType="solid"
                      endOpacity={0.1}
                      yAxisThickness={2}
                      xAxisThickness={2}
                      color={statistic.color}
                      animationDuration={1000}
                      endFillColor="lightgray"
                      backgroundColor="transparent"
                      yAxisLabelSuffix="% "
                      stepHeight={AppTheme.WP(10)}
                      startFillColor={statistic.color}
                      rulesColor={AppTheme.DefaultPalette().grey.light}
                      yAxisColor={AppTheme.DefaultPalette().borders.inputBorder}
                      xAxisColor={AppTheme.DefaultPalette().borders.inputBorder}
                      spacing={AppTheme.WP(10)}
                      yAxisTextStyle={{
                        fontSize: AppTheme.WP(2.2),
                        fontFamily: AppTheme.fonts.PoppinsMedium,
                        fontWeight: AppTheme.fontWeights.medium,
                        color: AppTheme.DefaultPalette().primary.contrastText,
                      }}
                      onPress={item => console.log('item onPress: ', item)}
                      pointerConfig={{
                        pointerStripUptoDataPoint: false,
                        pointerStripColor: AppTheme.DefaultPalette().grey.dark,
                        pointerStripWidth: 2,
                        strokeDashArray: [2, 5],
                        pointerColor: 'transparent',
                        radius: 4,
                        // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unstable-nested-components
                        pointerLabelComponent: items => {
                          return (
                            <PopoverWrapper>
                              <PopoverTitle>{items[0]?.title}</PopoverTitle>
                              <PopoverDetails borderBottom={true}>
                                <PopoverText
                                  style={{marginRight: AppTheme.WP(5)}}>
                                  {items[0]?.totalLabel}
                                </PopoverText>
                                <PopoverText
                                  style={{marginRight: AppTheme.WP(5)}}>
                                  {items[0]?.total}
                                </PopoverText>
                              </PopoverDetails>
                              <PopoverDetails borderBottom={false}>
                                <PopoverText
                                  style={{marginRight: AppTheme.WP(5)}}>
                                  {items[0]?.percentLabel}
                                </PopoverText>
                                <PopoverText
                                  style={{marginRight: AppTheme.WP(5)}}>
                                  {items[0]?.percent}
                                </PopoverText>
                              </PopoverDetails>
                            </PopoverWrapper>
                          );
                        },
                      }}
                    />
                  </GraphContainer>
                </GraphWrapper>
```

and here is the data points list

**List:**

```
[{"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jan 1 - Jan 8", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jan 9 - Jan 15", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jan 16 - Jan 22", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "100.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jan 23 - Jan 29", "total": 3, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 100}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "33.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jan 30 - Feb 5", "total": 3, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 33}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "100.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Feb 6 - Feb 12", "total": 3, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 100}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Feb 13 - Feb 19", "total": 1, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Feb 20 - Feb 26", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "50.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Feb 27 - Mar 5", "total": 2, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 50}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "67.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Mar 6 - Mar 12", "total": 3, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 67}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "67.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Mar 13 - Mar 19", "total": 3, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 67}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Mar 20 - Mar 26", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Mar 27 - Apr 2", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Apr 3 - Apr 9", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Apr 10 - Apr 16", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "50.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Apr 17 - Apr 23", "total": 2, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 50}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Apr 24 - Apr 30", "total": 3, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "50.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of May 1 - May 7", "total": 2, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 50}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "50.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of May 8 - May 14", "total": 4, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 50}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "25.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of May 15 - May 21", "total": 4, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 25}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "75.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of May 22 - May 28", "total": 4, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 75}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "75.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of May 29 - Jun 4", "total": 4, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 75}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "67.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jun 5 - Jun 11", "total": 3, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 67}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "60.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jun 12 - Jun 18", "total": 5, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 60}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jun 19 - Jun 25", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jun 26 - Jul 2", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jul 3 - Jul 9", "total": 2, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "50.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jul 10 - Jul 16", "total": 4, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 50}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "57.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jul 17 - Jul 23", "total": 7, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 56.99999999999999}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "25.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jul 24 - Jul 30", "total": 4, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 25}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Jul 31 - Aug 6", "total": 3, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "50.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Aug 7 - Aug 13", "total": 4, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 50}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Aug 14 - Aug 20", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Aug 21 - Aug 27", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Aug 28 - Sep 3", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Sep 4 - Sep 10", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "67.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Sep 11 - Sep 17", "total": 3, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 67}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "50.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Sep 18 - Sep 24", "total": 2, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 50}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Sep 25 - Oct 1", "total": 2, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "100.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Oct 2 - Oct 8", "total": 3, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 100}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "67.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Oct 9 - Oct 15", "total": 3, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 67}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": "75.0%", "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Oct 16 - Oct 22", "total": 4, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 75}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Oct 23 - Oct 29", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Oct 30 - Nov 5", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Nov 6 - Nov 12", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Nov 13 - Nov 19", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Nov 20 - Nov 26", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Nov 27 - Dec 3", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Dec 4 - Dec 10", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Dec 11 - Dec 17", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Dec 18 - Dec 24", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}, {"customDataPoint": [Function customDataPoint], "labelComponent": [Function labelComponent], "percent": 0, "percentLabel": "Break Percentage", "title": "Week of Dec 25 - Dec 31", "total": 0, "totalLabel": "Total Break", "value": 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Initially, I made use of the scrollable x-axis feature since I have 52 data points, but when I integrated the pointerConfig, the scrolling functionality ceased to work. To work around this, I implemented a ScrollView, which addressed the scrolling issue but, unfortunately, caused the tooltip to become non-functional for data points that fall outside the current view.

**pointerConfig** disables the scroll, but to fix it you don't need to implement your own ScrollView. Instead, you need to add the property `activatePointersOnLongPress: true` inside the **pointerConfig** object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about **pointerConfig**, because whenever I use **pointerConfig**, it doesn't allow me to scroll horizontally even if I'm not using the **ScrollView**, but the way I have solved it is by using the **onFocus** from **LineChart**

onFocus={item => setGraphData(item)}

and then according to the **graphData** being set, I'm showing the state above the graph

**here is the code**

```
const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState({});

return (
    <View>
      {refreshing ? (
        <ChartPointSkeleton />
      ) : isObjEmpty(graphData) ? (
        <EmptyGraphPoint />
      ) : (
        <RowCenter style={{marginBottom: AppTheme.WP(5)}}>
          <CardWrapper>
            <ChartPoint data={graphData} />
          </CardWrapper>
        </RowCenter>
      )}

      {isObjEmpty(BallsData) ? (
        <EmptyStates title={'No stats to display yet!'} />
      ) : (
        <GraphWrapper>
          <LineChart
            areaChart
            isAnimated
            thickness={3}
            maxValue={100}
            startOpacity={1}
            noOfSections={5}
            data={chartData}
            rulesType="solid"
            endOpacity={0.1}
            yAxisThickness={2}
            xAxisThickness={2}
            focusEnabled={true}
            yAxisLabelSuffix="% "
            color={statistic.color}
            endFillColor="lightgray"
            animationDuration={1000}
            backgroundColor="transparent"
            startFillColor={statistic.color}
            onFocus={item => setGraphData(item)}
            rulesColor={AppTheme.DefaultPalette().grey.light}
            yAxisColor={AppTheme.DefaultPalette().borders.inputBorder}
            xAxisColor={AppTheme.DefaultPalette().borders.inputBorder}
            yAxisTextStyle={{
              fontSize: AppTheme.WP(2.2),
              fontFamily: AppTheme.fonts.PoppinsMedium,
              fontWeight: AppTheme.fontWeights.medium,
              color: AppTheme.DefaultPalette().primary.contrastText,
            }}
          />
        </GraphWrapper>
      )}
    </View>
  );
```

[image]
[image]